# Rails private messages how to create a conversation view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using this gem for private messages: https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages

I want to create a thread conversation instead of the e-mail conversation the scaffold have provided.

Example, User A have sent 10 messages to User B. User A have also sent 10 messages to User C.

Instead of looping through all the messages. (e-mail look) I want to create a threat like:

**Inbox**

```
Conversation with User A (10 messages)
Conversation with User C (10 messages)
```

And when clicking on the conversation the messages should be ordered after date. So it would be like a conversation.

The table for messages:

```
id
sender_id
recipient_id
sender_deleted
recipient_deleted
subject
body
read_at
created_at
updated_at
```

How do I create these views? How do I group the messages?

Comment: What _specifically_ about this problem is tripping you up. That's potentially a lot of stuff to cover.

Comment: How do I group the messages? So I would have a array like [["User A", "10"], ["User B", "10"]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: you can't with that gem. You'll have to extend it and add a Conversation model then bridge that between users and messages.

I propose, instead, you use this gem:

https://github.com/ging/mailboxer

Far more powerful than your current gem, and it comes with conversations out of the box. I've used it before to mimic a gmail-like view.

From the guide:

```
#alfa wants to retrieve all his conversations
alfa.mailbox.conversations

#A wants to retrieve his inbox
alfa.mailbox.inbox

#A wants to retrieve his sent conversations
alfa.mailbox.sentbox

#alfa wants to retrieve his trashed conversations
alfa.mailbox.trash
```

Easy as pie:

```
current_user.mailbox.conversations.each do |convo|
  convo.subject
  ...
end
```

Comment: It should be possible with this gem, it does have all the tables, information etc. Just know how to group.

Comment: But it isn't, by default, because it is ignorant to conversations. If you plan to have only a single conversation possible between two users, then it is possible to do that with this gem, but I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: I think it is god to know how to solve this problem, instead of just switching gems.

Comment: The thing is it is bad design to group these the way you want. What happens if somebody wants to have a conversation about something else with the same user? It is horrible from a user perspective. There isn't a better time to switch gems than early on in a project. Why use something which can't even stand up with simple beginnings?

Comment: I see I will take a look on that gem.

Comment: The gem is a mess :/ Bad documentation etc.. :(

Comment: Bad documentation? The tests are your documentation, which it has. It's not a mess, it is just very powerful. It is one of the more popular messaging gems for Rails: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/User_Messaging_Systems. You don't have to use it, but the gem you are currently using doesn't even support conversations by default. Every message has a 'subject' like you are sending separate emails.